# How to use `Environ("USERPROFILE")` to open workbook on desktop , while desktop location changed to another drive (D)?

Tags: excel, vba, windows

On my work PC, I have no write on system drive (c). 
So, I have used `properties` of desktop folder and changed location of it to another drive (d). 
From windows 10,  I am using my desktop from that drive (d) similarly as it was on drive (c). 
**Problem**: I tried this vba code to open workbook on my desktop

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Query1.xls")
```

,but I got this error
`Run-time error 1004:Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\Query1.xls. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?` 
I am asking this question, as I use excel files on my work pc and my laptop (no restriction) interchangeably 
And it is hard to change my vba codes every time I change my machine. 
As always , thanks for any help.

Comment: My Desktop folder is currently at `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\DeskTop"` or `Environ("OneDrive") & "\DeskTop"`. But seeing the message you got, I'm not sure that it's gonna be of any use. A nice trick is to locate the folder manually and if it is not obvious, you could right-click in it and create a new excel workbook. When you open it, add a module and use `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FullName` in a sub or just use `?ThisWorkbook.FullName` in the Immediate window (`Ctrl+G`).

Comment: @VBasic2008 the path on new location is `D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\Query1.xls`, But the problem this path will raise error when I open my workbooks from my laptop , as path is different (`C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\Query1.xls`)

Comment: Is there OneDrive installed  on that computer? Try right  click on the workbook icon and see its real fullname in Properties. It may include OneDrive... this should be only a possibility.

Comment: Please, try `Debug.Print CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`?

Comment: Wasn't `OneDrive` installed on one of the two computers in discussion? Did you try the code line I suggested above?

Comment: What does "good" mean? Which is the difference between the two returned paths? What other application folder has been inserted between the user and `Desktop` one?

Comment: I do not care about accepting my answer. I didn't even place an answer. I always try understanding what is happening. And what you say cannot be true, I'm afraid. Except the fact that `Environ("USERPROFILE")` returns differently on the two involved computers. Which I think it is very improbable, but otherwise there is no logical explanation.

Comment: @FaneDuru , If you do not believe me (it is your own) , But you can try with your machine.
Instead of trying with desktop folder try `Favorites Folder` from `properties` of Favorites folder change location of it to another drive (D).
Then try this code in immediate window `Debug.Print CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Favorites")`

Comment: I cannot get you and I start thinking I am wasting my time. I know very well how to determine all special folders. What I tried emphasizing is only the next aspect: If your initial code raised an error on one of the two involved computers, **this only means that the returned path on one of them was different for the Desktop folder**. If you are not able to understand this aspect I do not know how else to explain it. It is not possible that both of them to be the same! Not necessary to reply. Only think about that... Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vbscript `SpecialFolders`.

```
   Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   strPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

See full list [here](https://ss64.com/vb/special.html).

```
Function Desktop() As String
'returns the path to Desktop 
    Desktop = CreateObject("wscript.shell").specialfolders("desktop")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

### Desktop on Different Drives

**Get it in a sub**

```vb
Sub DirDesktop()
    Dim DeskTopPath As String: DeskTopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    If Len(Dir(DeskTopPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        DeskTopPath = Replace(DeskTopPath, "C", "D", , 1)
    End If
    Debug.Print DeskTopPath & "Query1.xls"
End Sub
```

**Get it using a function**

```vb
Sub GetDeskTopTEST()
    Dim DeskTopPath As String: DeskTopPath = GetDeskTop
    Debug.Print DeskTopPath & "Query1.xls"
End Sub

Function GetDeskTop() As String
    GesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    If Len(Dir(GetDeskTop, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        GetDeskTop = Replace(GetDeskTop, "C", "D", , 1)
    End If
End Function
```

**Here's another idea**

You can set your own *Environ* variables.
Go to `Windows Settings > About >` scroll down to `Advanced Settings` and at the bottom click on `Environment Variables`. Click the upper `New` box and in the `Variable Name` box use e.g. `DeskTop` and in the `Variable value` box use the path. If you do this on both computers, you can on both of them access the folder with `Environ("DeskTop")`. You have to restart Excel for this to take effect.

Comment: I tried on my `work PC` and works perfectly, I will try today on my laptop and feed you back.
also, IT restricted set my own Environ variables ☹.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check if it finds the file, else set a different path.